# Javascript sort table column on click

Tags: javascript, html

My intention is to sort a table column (only the clicked th's column) in ascending order when `th` is being clicked. On further click the exact table column shall be ordered in a descending order.

**What I got so far: 

The table is being sorted, but on click all three columns are being sorted - I only want one column to be sorted.**

```js
function sortTable(n) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";

    while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;

        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

            if (dir == "asc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (dir == "desc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount ++;
        } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Nummer</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Land</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Rumänien</td>
        <td>Dan</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Deutschland</td>
        <td>Aaron</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Some suggestions to improve the question: You should be clear about what you expect the code to do, and what it actually does. You also should explain what you think the problem is, and why. And ideally, make the example code runnable.

Comment: @AlexMA I've updated the post, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This also looks like extreme overkill for the description. If all you want to do is sort your rows, then the code for that is a few lines:

```
function compareValues(a, b) {
  // return -1/0/1 based on what you "know" a and b
  // are here. Numbers, text, some custom case-insensitive
  // and natural number ordering, etc. That's up to you.
  // A typical "do whatever JS would do" is:
  return (a<b) ? -1 : (a>b) ? 1 : 0;
}

function sortTable(colnum) {
  // get all the rows in this table:
  let rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll(`tr`));

  // but ignore the heading row:
  rows = rows.slice(1);

  // set up the queryselector for getting the indicated
  // column from a row, so we can compare using its value:
  let qs = `td:nth-child(${colnum})`;

  // and then just... sort the rows:
  rows.sort( (r1,r2) => {
    // get each row's relevant column
    let t1 = r1.querySelector(qs);
    let t2 = r2.querySelector(qs);

    // and then effect sorting by comparing their content:
    return compareValues(t1.textContent,t2.textContent);
  });

  // and then the magic part that makes the sorting appear on-page:
  rows.forEach(row => table.appendChild(row));
}
```

The magic part works because DOM nodes can only exist in one place, so if you `appendChild` it to something, it gets *moved* from wherever it was in the first place. As such, we sort in JS, and then we run `appendChild` in that sorted order, every row is simply moved from "whereever it was" to "the end of the child list", which means after we run through every row in `rows`, presto: all the rows are now reordered as needed.

Of course you're still on the hook for writing `compareValues(a,b)` yourself. I don't know what you want to do there, because maybe you want natural text compare, or maybe you want "if the values are numbers, compare as numbers, only if they're not compare as text", etc.

But one thing you *should* do is not use 1998 event handling. Don't use `onclick`, do this properly on the JS side. So in your HTML:

```
<tr>
  <th>Nummer</th>
  <th>Land</th>
  <th>Name</th>
</tr>
```

And then on the JS side:

```
table.querySelectorAll(`th`).forEach((th, position) => {
  th.addEventListener(`click`, evt => sortTable(position));
});
```

(and better yet, use `<th><button>Nummer</button></th>` and add the event listener based on `th button`, because that's what it is. If you have text that can be clicked to "do something", that's a button. Use the correct markup, and then just use CSS to style it however you want, e.g. no border, background:inherit, etc)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to JavaScript - you told me to not use the old event handling and showed me an alternative. But where do I use both, the function and the eventListener, how do I arrange them in my .js file (since the console tells me that `table` is not defined)?

Comment: normally anything you give an `id` attribute magically becomes a directly-usable variable on the JS side, but if that is not the case you can put `let table = document.getElementById('table')` at whatever is the most sensible "highest level" so that you can use it directly in your functions. Where you put functions is almost always irrelevant: JS "hoists" functions by reading all of them in _first_, before actually running your code. One of the lesser documented features of JS, but a super important one to know about.

Comment: I smh get another error: `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'td:nth-child(undefined' is not a valid selector.` and furthermore, where do I exactly put a hook to compare the values?

Comment: That looks like a pretty obvious error? The `colnum` variable, which we know should be a number, is showing as `undefined` in the error message, so maybe you forgot to pass it in - have a look at where you're adding the event listener, and make sure you're passing in the th's position to the call to `sortTable`. As for the comparison function, it just has to live anywhere that is in scope for the `sortTable` function, so the obvious choice is "above or below it". I've updated the answer with a stub for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans)' answer works very well except the sorted table will place the `<tr>`s outside the `<tbody>` tag, which is undesired.
This can be easily solved by changing his answer to this:

```js
function sortTable(colnum) {
  let tbody = table.querySelector(`tbody`);
  let rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll(`tr`));
  
  // other codes...
  
  rows.forEach(row => tbody.appendChild(row));
}
```

Then the generated table should be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a different approach. Store your data and sort the array before rendering.

```js
let tblData = [{
    number: 2,
    land: 'Rumänien',
    name: 'Dan'
  },
  {
    number: 1,
    land: 'Deutschland',
    name: 'Aaron'
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    land: 'USA',
    name: 'Peter'
  }
];

const getRow = (data) => `<tr><td>${data.number}</td><td>${data.land}</td><td>${data.name}</td></tr>`;

const sortNumber = (a, b) => a.number - b.number;
const sortLand = (a, b) => (a.land === b.land) ? 0 : (a.land > b.land) ? 1 : -1;
const sortName = (a, b) => (a.name === b.name) ? 0 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1;

function buildTable(data) {
document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = data.map(row => getRow(row)).join('');
}

function sortTable(n) {
  let sort = sortNumber;
  switch (n) {
    case 1:
      sort = sortLand;
      break;
    case 2:
      sort = sortName;
  }
  console.log(n);
  buildTable(tblData.sort(sort));
}

buildTable(tblData);
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Nummer</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Land</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No need, `appendChild` makes it really easy to sort the HTMLelements in JS, and then effect the reordering in the DOM with a `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, I get the results that I would expect. I wonder if it seems like the results aren't correct simply because your data is setup that way.

For example, your data is:

```
1   Deutschland Aaron
2   Rumänien    Dan
3   USA Peter
```

And sorting on Number, would have Deutschland First with Aaron, and both Deutschland and Aaron are alphabetically first before the rest of the data.

So its an illusion that the other columns are being sorted, when in fact they are actually just following your data structure.